# How to find $[A]_B^B$ when you have the orthonormal basis $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

Let $A:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear operator such that
\begin{align*}
    A\left(\begin{bmatrix}
            1\\
            3\\
            6
            \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
            9\\
            28\\
            23
            \end{bmatrix},\quad\quad A\left(\begin{bmatrix}
            -3\\
            -5\\
            6
            \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
            13\\
            44\\
            39
            \end{bmatrix},\quad\quad A\left(\begin{bmatrix}
            3\\
            3\\
            4
            \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
            11\\
            24\\
            17
            \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Find $A\left(\begin{bmatrix}
            x\\
            y\\
            z
            \end{bmatrix}\right)$ for any $\begin{bmatrix}
            x\\
            y\\
            z
            \end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

I have calculated $A\left(\begin{bmatrix}
            x\\
            y\\
            z
            \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
            3 & -2 & 2\\
            4 & -4 & 6\\
            2 & -3 & 5
            \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
            x\\
            y\\
            z
            \end{bmatrix}$.

Next, Equip $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the dot product. Apply the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process to the basis for $\mathbb{R}^3, \left\{\begin{bmatrix}
            1\\
            3\\
            6
            \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
            -3\\
            -5\\
            6
            \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
            3\\
            3\\
            4
            \end{bmatrix}\right\}$, to obtain an orthonormal basis $B$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Find $[A]_B^B$.

**I have found the orthonormal basis $B$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$ (shown below), but I don't know what to do next to find $[A]_B^B$.**

How I calculated for the orthonormal basis $B$:

Notice that the second and third vectors are already orthogonal.
\begin{align*}
                (-3, -5, 6)\cdot(3, 3, 4) &= (-3)(3) + (-5)(3) + (6)(4)\\
                &= -9 - 15 + 24\\
                &= 0
            \end{align*}
Therefore, we only need a third vector:
\begin{align*}
                (-3, -5, 6)\cdot(x,y,z) &= 0\\
                -3x-5y+6z &= 0\\\\
                (3, 3, 4)\cdot(x, y, z) &= 0\\
                3x + 3y + 4z &= 0\\\\
                -3x-5y+6z + 3x + 3y + 4z &= -2y + 10z
            \end{align*}
Assume $z = t$, then $y = 5t$:
\begin{align*}
                -3x - 25t + 6t &= 0\\
                x &= -\dfrac{19}{3}t
            \end{align*}
Let $t = 3$, then $x = 19, y = 15, z = 3$. So we get the third vector
\begin{align*}
                (-19, 15, 3)
            \end{align*}
Thus, performing the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process,
\begin{align*}
                B &= \left\{\begin{bmatrix}
                                -\frac{3\sqrt{70}}{70}\\-\frac{\sqrt{70}}{14}\\\frac{3\sqrt{70}}{35}
                \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
                                \frac{3\sqrt{34}}{34}\\\frac{3\sqrt{34}}{34}\\\frac{2\sqrt{34}}{17}
                \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
                                -\frac{19\sqrt{595}}{595}\\\frac{3\sqrt{595}}{119}\\\frac{3\sqrt{595}}{595}
                \end{bmatrix}\right\}
            \end{align*}